# Pins order shows up in reverse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold, pins

I am working on a scaffold pins rails app. On the app there are three models, pins, users and categories. Initially the pins should show up with the earliest pins at the very bottom, and the latest ones at the very top. However, this order seems to be reversed when the pins are at the users and categories show page, they have the earliest pins at the top and the latest one hid at the bottom.

Looking at my pins model, I do have the below code, it doesn't make sense if I add the below code in to users and categories model.

pin.rb

```
 find(:all, order: "created_at desc")
```

Comment: can you show us the code for the users and categories show page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the show action for your users controller and the show action for your categories controller:

```
@pins = Pin.order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: That did make the orders of the pins right. However,now all my categories and different users are showing all the pins available. But  not pins assigned to a specific category or uploaded by an user. How do I fix that?

Comment: You can chain these query modifiers, so you should be able to find all pins uploaded by a user and belonging to a certain category by doing `@pins = @user.pins.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")`. This will only work if you have a `belongs_to` relationship in your pins model for both the user and category models.